# Get Realtime-Update of an Array of DocumentReferences

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, real-time-updates

I'm writing a Game, where the users can join a Lobby to play together. Therefore I update the Lobby and the Users, stored in Firestore. The Lobbys in the Lobby-Collection contain an Id, creator, creationDate and an array of all Members (DocumentReferences to User Objects in a Users Collection). The Users contain an Id, name, mail and an active Lobby. Now, when I update the Entries in the Firestore, in there (Firestore) they seem to be correct.. but when I receive a realtimeUpdate (by adding a SnapshotListener) the array of Members seem to be empty.. but I just inserted the Users to the Array and they ARE saved to Firestore..

Maybe nice to know: I convert the Datasets i get from Firestore to local Java-Objects for better handling with UI things

I also have a local HashMap to more or less cache the Objects so i dont have to always load the from Firestore (I know there is already a cache in the Firestore lib.. but i think i need my own)

At the moment I write the changes directly to Firestore and wait for them to come back via RealtimeUpdate to then update my local Objects. I also tried to update my local Objects and then write them to Firestore.. but then I only append my Users to the Members-Array and the array contains mulitple References of the same user..

```java
/**
     * Get a Lobby Object from a DocumentSnapshot from Firestrore
     * If the Object already exists it will be loaded from the "CacheMap"
     *
     * @param documentSnapshot DocumentSnapshot with the data from the Firestore
     * @param feedback         a method to call when the Lobby was retrieved
     */
    public static void getLobbyByDocSnap(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, IFeedback feedback) {
        final String METHOD = TAG + " #getLobbyByDocSnap";
        String lobby_id = documentSnapshot.getString(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_ID);

        if (allLoadedLobbys.containsKey(lobby_id)) {
            Log.d(METHOD, "found object in map for id: " + lobby_id);
            feedback.trigger(allLoadedLobbys.get(lobby_id));
            return;
        }
        Log.d(METHOD, "Could not find in Map.. generate through data");
        Lobby lobby = new Lobby();
        lobby.setId(lobby_id);
        lobby.setPrivateLobby(documentSnapshot.getBoolean(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_PRIVATELOBBY));
        lobby.setCreationDate(documentSnapshot.getDate(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_CREATIONDATE));
        allLoadedLobbys.put(lobby.getId(), lobby);


        //create all Members of the Lobby as User Objects
        final List<User> members = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DocumentReference> docmems = (List<DocumentReference>) documentSnapshot.get(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_MEMBER);
        Log.d(METHOD, "get all members of lobby: " + lobby_id);
        for (final DocumentReference docmem : docmems) {
            /*docmem.collection(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_MEMBER).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                        Log.d(METHOD, "Found Members for: "+lobby_id+": "+Arrays.toString(queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().toArray()));
                        //Convert DocumentReference to User-Object
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                            Log.d(METHOD, "Get User Object from "+UserManager.class.getCanonicalName());
                            UserManager.getUserByDocSnap(document, o -> members.add((User) o));
                        }
                    });*/

            UserManager.getUserByRef(docmem, o -> members.add((User) o));
        }
        lobby.setMember(members);

        Log.d(METHOD, "Start getting the Creator of this Lobby: " + lobby_id);
        //create an User-Object for the Creator
        UserManager.getUserByRef((DocumentReference) documentSnapshot.get(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_CREATOR), o -> {
            User creator = (User) o;
            lobby.setCreator(creator);

            Log.d(METHOD, "Got the Creator, now get the artist for: " + lobby_id);
            UserManager.getUserByRef((DocumentReference) documentSnapshot.get(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_ARTIST), a -> {
                User artist = (User) a;

                Log.d(METHOD, "Got the Artist. All Infos collected for: " + lobby_id);
                //Create The Lobby-Object
                lobby.setArtist(artist);

                Log.d(METHOD, "Save the Lobby to the CacheMap: " + lobby.toString());
                //add it to the given list and trigger the feedback
                feedback.trigger(lobby);
            });
        });

        documentSnapshot.getReference().addSnapshotListener((snapshot, e) -> {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(METHOD+"+new", "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }

            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d(METHOD + "*new", "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
                String update_lobby_id = snapshot.getString(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_ID);
                Lobby update_lobby = allLoadedLobbys.get(update_lobby_id);
                update_lobby.setCreationDate(snapshot.getDate(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_CREATIONDATE));
                update_lobby.setPrivateLobby(snapshot.getBoolean(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_PRIVATELOBBY));
                UserManager.getUserByRef(snapshot.getDocumentReference(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_ARTIST), o -> update_lobby.setArtist((User) o));
                UserManager.getUserByRef(snapshot.getDocumentReference(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_CREATOR), o -> update_lobby.setCreator((User) o));
                List<User> update_member = update_lobby.getMember();
                update_member.clear();
                List<DocumentReference> update_docmems = (List<DocumentReference>) documentSnapshot.get(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_MEMBER);
                //update_lobby.setMember(update_member);
                Log.d(METHOD+"*new", "get all updated members of lobby: " + update_lobby_id);
                Log.d(METHOD+"*new", "members DocRef List: " + update_docmems);
                /*for (final DocumentReference update_docmem : update_docmems) {
                    Log.d(METHOD+"*new", update_docmem.getId());
                    UserManager.getUserByRef(update_docmem, o -> {
                        Log.d(METHOD+"*new",((User) o).toString());
                        update_lobby.addMember((User) o);
                    });
                }*/
                getMemberList(update_docmems, new ArrayList<>(), o -> {
                    List<User> mems = (List<User>) o;
                    update_lobby.getMember().clear();
                    update_lobby.getMember().addAll(mems);
                });
            } else {
                Log.d(METHOD+"*new", "Current data: null");
            }
        });
    }

    private static void getMemberList(List<DocumentReference> update_docmems, List<User> member, IFeedback feedback){
        final String METHOD = TAG + " #getMemberList";
        /*if(null == member){
            member = new ArrayList<>();
        }*/
        if(update_docmems.isEmpty()){
            feedback.trigger(member);
            return;
        }

        DocumentReference docref = update_docmems.get(0);
        UserManager.getUserByRef(docref, o -> {
            member.add((User) o);
            Log.d(METHOD, o.toString());
            update_docmems.remove(0);
            getMemberList(update_docmems, member, feedback);
        });
    }
```

The Realtime only provides the "normal" Data but not the array of references. When I initialy load the Data from Firestore i get the actual Data of the Firestore (not empty). But I want to get the whole Document, inluding the "normal" Data (id, creationDate, ...) and the whole array of members.

I already burned 1.5 days to solve this and I cant figure out, whats wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i got my error.... really stupid one ^^

in the part where i updated my objects, when the firestore changes.. i used the wrong/old DocumentSnapshot. So I used the inital Members-Array not my new updated one :D

should be:

```java
List<DocumentReference> update_docmems = (List<DocumentReference>) snapshot.get(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_MEMBER);
```

instead of:

```java
List<DocumentReference> update_docmems = (List<DocumentReference>) documentSnapshot.get(FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_MEMBER);
```

Now i get my updates correctly :D